# How can I include jQuery and JavaScript code without straying from the site template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, site-template

I've added my JavaScript code by including the script links in the `PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead` `<asp:Content>` tag. Including this has caused a yellow warning stating

> The current page has been customized from its template. Revert to template.

I understand that I can simply remove the message through some JavaScript code, but how does Microsoft recommend I include JavaScript code and [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) without disrupting the site template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really depends what page you are talking about (master page, .aspx page, etc.), but you can add your script references in a Content Editor Web Part (CEWP) if you don't want to customize your pages.

Answer (score 6):

Are you running SharePoint 2010? If so, you can include your scripts using a feature: it is now possible to have a CustomAction with ScriptLink as a location. This will leave the masterpage unmodified while at the same time making jQuery (and any other scripts you need) available across the entire site collection. More information is in *[Deploying and Using jQuery with a SharePoint 2010 Sandboxed Solution](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2010/09/02/deploying-and-using-jquery-with-a-sharepoint-2010-sandboxed-solution.aspx)*.

Comment: Completely forgot about that one! That is, indeed, a nice solution.

Answer (score 3):

A warning doesn't mean that you did something wrong.

As far as I know there is no recommendation from Microsoft. There are many ways to add a script to a page, and your choice will depend on your specific use case and personal preferences.

Do you need jQuery on many pages? Then you may want to include it in a custom Master page. Do you need it on just one page? Then the easiest way is to call it from a Content Editor Web Part.

Comment: I like this contribution though not as complete as some of the other answers just because it mentions that the warning is just a warning.

Answer (score 3):

As Marc D Anderson stated, you can add script references in various ways. If you want to add JavaScript code on a single page, you can indeed use a Content Editor webpart, but I really like the solution of creating a feature and use delegate controls to add the JavaScript code to your page layouts. That way, you don't have to customize any page layouts.

Read *[jQuery Templates and the Sharepoint 2010 Object Model](https://sladescross.wordpress.com/category/placeholderadditionalpagehead/)* for information on adding JavaScript code to pages.

Comment: delegate controls means filesystem deployment, if you are on SP2010 and in a sandboxed environment this won't work

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended to customize any out of the box master pages or page layouts in SharePoint.  Instead, copy your existing master page to a new name and make your customizations in that, then set the new master page as the master page for your site collection.